# Synchronous Incomplete Assignment or How is Register Retention achieved

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I just realised that Latch creation upon incomplemete assignments only happen in a non clocked enviroment.
So far I have written all my synchronous code unnecessary avoiding incomplete assignments like this:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if X then
    if Y then
      reg <= '1';
    else
      reg <= reg;
    end if;
  else
    reg <= '0'
  end if;
end if;
```

This works fine for me. 
But for bigger constructs, explicit register retention like here,

```
else
  reg <= reg;
```

adds a lot of bloat to my code.

So I'm wondering if there is any difference at all in omiting the else statement(1).

Also how is "register retention" despite of a clock edge realised in the hardware itself(2)?

Normally the clock should update the register every cycle. Is the retention implemented like the explicit code above, with a mux between register output and '1', or is there some kind of disable for the register. (I remember from my digital design class that gating the clock is a bad idea).

Thank you for your Insight!

Comment: In a clocked process, incomplete assignment is fine : in the absence of an assignment, a register is inferred. In the hardware it will be an FF (or N FFs). So go ahead and clean up the bloat.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no assignment, the last value of the FF is kept in a synchronous process, in an asynchronous process a latch is inferred.

When there are several assignments to the same signal in the same process, the last one is applied.

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   if X then
      if Y then
         reg <= '1';
      else
         reg <= reg;
      end if;
   else
      reg <= '0'
   end if;
end if;
```

Can be rewritten as :

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   if X then
      if Y then
         reg <= '1';
      end if;
   else
      reg <= '0';
   end if;
end if;
```

Or :

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   reg <= '0';
   if X then
      if Y then
         reg <= '1';
      else
         reg <= reg;
      end if;
   end if;
end if;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 6.1.3.1 Edge-sensitive storage from a process with sensitivity list and one clock.